# How to remove HTML tags on saving data in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a problem on this editor, where after I save my data the HTML tags like `<b><strong> etc..` are also saved. How can I removed those tags and just display the saved data without html tags?

> I've managed to remove the `<p>` tag but the other tags are still displaying like `<b><strong>` etc.

```
    <script>tinymce.init({
        forced_root_block : "", 
        selector:'textarea'});
    </script>
```

In the header I declared the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you using an HTML rich text editor if all you want is plain text?  For that you could just use a simple `textarea`.

Comment: @MichaelFromin - no, I also need to put `bold` `italic` and `etc...` on saving my data. do you have any advice or suggestion?

Comment: How do you propose to get that without the HTML markup?

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://htmlpurifier.org to remove undesired HTML tags.